# How can I add images in a button to a table without slow loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have 2 ways of adding images to a table and, which is most efficient, and is there a better way? Both ways are place on top of a button with "layer object".

Aslo I notice that the table scrolls slowly in the simulator, will this slow scrolling possibly take place on a real phone? The only reason I see why is possibly because I haven;t related the button, but it could be something else related to memory, or drawing in each cell. I can't be because the images come from URL's right?

Here are the 2 ways I add each button to the table cell:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[button setTitle:@"image.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[[button titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13]];

[button setTitleColor:[UIColor clearColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

UIImage *btn = [UIImage imageWithData:"png image from url"];

UIImage* newImage2 = [btn scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(280, 209.0)];

CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(280, 209.0);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);

[newImage2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, (newSize.width), (newSize.height))];

UIImage *newImage4 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();   

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[button setImage:newImage4 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

button.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 50.0, 280, 255.0);
```

////////////////////////////////////////// Second Way below:

```
UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[button2 setTitle:@"photo.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[[button2 titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13]];

[button2 setTitleColor:[UIColor clearColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageWithData:"png image from url"];

UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:btnImage];

imageView2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 209);

button2.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 50.0, 280, 255.0);

[button2 addSubview:imageView2];
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, still learning how to use this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here some of your images are coming from remote server. You should use [lazy loading](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) to load images from remote server. It will download image asynchronously and load image according to need. You can also use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) library which do this & also have caching mechanism. Using this library is very easy & straight forward. like:

```
 [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: ok thanks, that made things faster but there still is some lag